# If using an autoreleasepool to control references to a realm, is it good practice to call realm.invalidate before leaving the pool

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have an application that does a lot of background reading of a realm, during which time, another background thread (i.e. not the main thread) may be writing to the same realm, so I am using an autoreleasepool on the background threads to ensure the thread reference to the realm is reclaimed quickly.  See excerpt below

```
autoreleasepool {
    do {
        let backgroundRealm = try Realm(configuration: self.configuration)

        .... Do lots of reading

        backgroundRealm.beginWrite() 

        .... Do lots of writing here

        try backgroundRealm.commitWrite()

        // Is this good practice or not?
        backgroundRealm.invalidate()
    }
    catch {
        ....
    }
}
```

From reading the documentation [Using a realm across threads](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#using-a-realm-across-threads) and [inWriteTransaction](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html#/s:vC10RealmSwift5Realm18inWriteTransactionSb), it is not clear if after the `commitWrite()` and/or before leaving the autoreleasepool, would a call to `backgroundRealm.invalidate()` help keep file sizes down and improve performance?  Does this implicitly happen when the realm is reclaimed behind the scenes?  Would the call to `invalidate()` only waste CPU cycles and provide no additional benefits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would a call to `backgroundRealm.invalidate()` help keep file sizes down and improve performance?

No. `invalidate()` has no impact on the file size. If you want to keep the file size down, you would need to use `writeCopyToURL(_:, encryptionKey:_, error: _)` to write a compacted copy. But there is no convenience method for an in-place compact, which would require to invalidate all accessors across threads.

> Does this implicitly happen when the realm is reclaimed behind the scenes?

It wouldn't be necessary. A Realm is deallocated, when there isn't any acccessor left keeping a hold off it anymore. So there is nothing left to be invalidated.

> Would the call to invalidate() only waste CPU cycles and provide no additional benefits?

As long as you don't leak accessors from your autoreleasepool, you should be fine. Calling `invalidate()` might help if you leak objects to locate these later at runtime. But take care: when you access an invalidated object, it will fail.

Comment: Ok, so `invalidate()` is unnecessary and the space will be reclaimed in subsequent writes, but in the invalidate() doc, when it says:

    _This method should be called before performing long blocking operations  on a background thread on which you previously read data from the Realm which you no longer need._

What benefit are we gaining from that call?